# How to sign out with Dropbox Java SDK v2?

Tags: java, android, sdk, dropbox

I'm migrating from Dropbox Java SDK v1 to SDK v2 and i can't figure out how to sign out (unlink) programmatically after the user logged in? I've checked out an [example](https://github.com/dropbox/dropbox-sdk-java) and compiled/launched android example but i can't see it's available. Should i just forget `accessToken`?

It can be common use case as my app can have multiple users.
Also i've noted browser window remains opened after the user logged in and my app is closed. Any change to force `AuthActivity` to close on 'Accept' or 'Cancel' button clicked in it.

Comment: See [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Seems you did not understand - nobody is going to guess what exactly you are currently doing.

Comment: "can't figure out how to sign out (unlink) programmatically after the user logged in" isn't it clear enough for you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you should throw away the access token when the user no longer wants to use the account in the app. You can also explicitly revoke the token on the server. There's some more information on this in this [GitHub issue](https://github.com/dropbox/dropbox-sdk-java/issues/92).